# FIre beforeSave on updateAll

Tags: php, callback, cakephp-2.0

I need to trigger beforeSave() and afterSave() callbacks on updateAll(). I use updateAll() because I need update ID field.. (I knew it kinda 'wrong' about editable-ID thing, but this database I used is already messy like that).

What I need to do is, trigger the updateAll() to fire beforeSave() and afterSave(), just like save() does.

Here is a hack of updateAll() in CakePHP 1.3

```
function updateAll($fields, $conditions = true) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $output = call_user_func_array(array('parent', 'updateAll'), $args);
    if ($output) {
        $created = false;
        $options = array();
        $this->Behaviors->trigger($this, 'afterSave', array(
           $created,
           $options,
       ));

       $this->afterSave($created);
       $this->_clearCache();
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then this is the code I adjusted in CakePHP 2.3

```
function updateAll($fields, $conditions = true) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $output = call_user_func_array(array('parent', 'updateAll'), $args);
    if ($output) {
       $created = false;
       $options = array();
       $event = new CakeEvent('Model.afterSave', $this, array($created, $options));
       $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);

       $this->afterSave($created);
       $this->_clearCache();
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is, what if I wanna call beforeSave() in the updateAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a dumb-question I had.

Here is the code:

```
function updateAll($fields, $conditions = true) {

    $options = array();
    $event = new CakeEvent('Model.beforeSave', $this, array($options) );
    list($event->break, $event->breakOn) = array(true, array(false, null));
    $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);

    $args = func_get_args();
    $output = call_user_func_array(array('parent', 'updateAll'), $args);
    if ($output) {
      $created = false;
      $options = array();
      $event = new CakeEvent('Model.afterSave', $this, array($created, $options));
      $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);

      $this->afterSave($created);
      $this->_clearCache();
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```